# terraform how can I find the ARN for bucket created on module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm creating a bucket using a module, how can I find the ARN for that bucket?

create the module

```
module "testbucket" {
 source         = "github.com/tomfa/terraform-sandbox/s3-webfiles-bucket"
 aws_region     = "${var.aws_region}"
 aws_access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
 aws_secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
 bucket_name    = "${var.bucket_name}-test"
}
```

Then when I call the policy I need access to the ARN

```
 {
    "Sid": "accessToS3",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.${var.bucket_name}.arn}",
    ]
}
```

I am not referencing the ARN so i get the error:

> > > Error: resource 'aws_iam_role_policy.policy_Demo_lambda' config: unknown resource 'aws_s3_bucket.mybukk' referenced in variable aws_s3_bucket.mybukk.arn

How to access my ARN? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your module will need to have an [outputs.tf file](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/outputs.html), looking like this:

```
output "bucket_arn" {
  value = "${aws_s3_bucket.RESOURCE_NAME.arn}"
}
```

Please note that you will have to replace RESOURCE_NAME with the name of the terraform S3 bucket resource.

For example, if your resource looks like this: `resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {...` then you will need to replace RESOURCE_NAME to b

then you can call it in your policy:

```
{
    "Sid": "accessToS3",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "${module.testbucket.bucket_arn}",
    ]
}
```

Comment: hi Thomas, I get a syntax error: expected "}" but found invalid sequence "$"

Comment: You will have to replace RESOURCE_NAME in the outputs file to the name of he S3 resource. Added that in the answer

Answer (score 5):

###This can be accomplished in two ways after terraform apply has been executed:

Create a file called outputs.tf in your working directory. In that file you can use one of the two methods below.

**1 - if you already have a variable for this resource defined:**

```
output "S3-Bucket-Name" {
  value = "${var.bucket_name.arn}"
}
```

**2 - if you want to call the resource directly:**

```
output "S3-Bucket-Name" {
  value = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket_name.arn}"
}
```